# unexpected behaviour in option tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I have the following code

```
<select id="part">
<option>noun</option>
<option>verb</option>
<option>adjective</option>
</select>
```

In the above code, I don't have any value attribute each option tag.
there is only text node.

when I access the option tag 
`$("#part").val();` I get what is selected in dropdown box. ie, "noun"
but when I access `$("#part").text()`, there is empty string.

but when I create, option tags dynamically in jquery for

```
<select id="part"></select>
```

using

```
var names=["noun","adjective","verb"];
for (var i =0;i<names.length;i++) {
    var option=$("<option>",{
            value:names[i],
            text:names[i]});
    $("#part").append(option);
}
```

Here the value is attribute is needed to get the option selected.
without value attribute, $("#part") is undefined.

can somebody explain the discrepancy here? of if my understanding is not correct. Thanks

Comment: `$("#part").text()` _doesn't_ give an empty string (at least not in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/EXr8S/ - note though that you were missing a `"` so your `$("#part).text()` wouldn't have worked at all. Please edit your question to reword the sentence starting "Here the value is attribute" (because as is it makes no sense - are you trying to say that if you leave the `value` attribute out of that jQuery code in the loop then the result doesn't work?).

Comment: What @nnnnn said. And pro-tip: define `var $part = $("#part")` and use is inside the `for` cycle.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I have edited the code for that typo (missing ") and rephrased the question. I am using firefox to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/yH4Fb/

You need to get only the selected option text coz there are three options,

when you get `$("#part").val();` you directly get the selected value (only one selected value). But when you get `$("#part").text()`.. you are getting the text of the whole select text where you have three options and three types of text.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var names=["noun","adjective","verb"];
    for (var i =0;i<names.length;i++) {
        var option=$("<option>",{
                value:names[i],
                text:names[i]});
        $("#part").append(option);
    }
    
    $("#part").on('change', function() {
        alert('Value is '+$(this).val());
        var text = $("#part option:selected").text();
        alert('Text is '+text);
    });        
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`$("#part").text()` doesn't return nothing but it won't return what you expect ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Assimilater/EXr8S/4/)).

Explanation: text returns the text of the object strips out the html ([see jQuery docs examples](http://api.jquery.com/text/)), so what you will be getting is the inner contents of the select after the html was stripped out.

If you want the text of the selected value, include the selected option in your jquery selector: i.e. `$('#part option:selected').text()` which uses the [jQuery psuedo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) (also in my fiddle).